# Remove Name Suffix in a file using Sed in linux

Tags: linux, sed

I have one csv file including name information with suffix.

```
LNAME,Date
MURRY-IV,1990
SMITH,1998
DEL-IVY,2000
EDWARD-IV,1990
```

I want to remove all those suffix parts. My expected output should be

```
LNAME,Date
MURRY,1990
SMITH,1998
DEL-IVY,2000
EDWARD,1990
```

To do that, I used `sed 's/-IV//g' filename`. But the output became

```
LNAME,Date
MURRY,1990
SMITH,1998
DELY,2000
EDWARD,1990
```

So the name **DEL-IVY** was revised as well. How shall I get around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Match `-IV` followed by a comma....

```
sed 's/-IV,/,/'
```

Comment: Not part of the exanple data, but perhaps the last field must be replaced: `sed -r 's/IV(,|$)/\1/g'`.